# WebGL builds and VR/Oculus build in same project

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I have a project I intend to have two clients ; a VR client and a WebGL client. I am using the Oculus Integration package as well to build to Oculus Quest.

While everything runs correctly in Android, when I try to build the project in WebGL, I have an error concerning the Microphone class.

When stubbing it, build work but the WebGL player cause the following error :
"To use dlopen, you need to use Emscripten's linking support"

This error looks to be caused by Oculus Integration, because when removed, the player works successfuly.

Is there a way to make WebGL and Oculus Integration work in the same project ? There is very few things different between clients, so I'd rather not having separate projects, because sharing code is such a chore in Unity.

Thanks !

Comment: While Ive not worked with vr surely you can use conditional defines to comment in/out great chunks of code, so you can do build with optional of webgl do this, else do that.. In fact I think you can even do that without having to make your own defines

Comment: @BugFinder Unfortunately, the code causing issue is from the Oculus package, and it would be very unconvenient (but, I admit, possible) to alter all their scripts to add conditional compilation.

Comment: Well, you could keep two copies the packages json file, one for webgl one without and just swap them....

Comment: @BugFinder The Oculus Integration is a .unitypackage from the Asset Store and is not in the package.json file.

Comment: Well, you have choices, they just arent easy

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution for this? I'm facing the same problems. In the oculus integration package i've deleted all the Microphone classes (Avatar/* and LipSync/*) Didn't needed it anyway. But i've the exception "to use dlopen, you need to use emscripten's linking support".

Comment: @TiesTheunissen I assume you asked me as well on the post on the Unity forum ? I copied back my answer here for reference.

Comment: yes indeed. thnx for the answer :), I must look into the logical links. never worked with that before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually worked around by making actually two separated projects ; a WebGL and a Oculus. My assets got on both projects using a folder with logical links, and only the Oculus project had the Oculus integration & Unity XR dependencies installed.

For the few of my scripts depending on XR, I used `#if UNITY_WEBGL`/`#if !UNITY_WEBGL` to disable them in the WebGL project.